# @HiltWorker annotation can not be found

Tags: android, android-workmanager, dagger-hilt

I wanted to use WorkManager with Hilt. I followed the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack?authuser=4) and integrated the required dependencies like this into my gradle file:

```
// WorkManager library
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"
// To use WorkManager with Hilt
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-work:workmanager_hilt_version"  
// Annotation processor when using Kotlin
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:workmanager_hilt_version"
```

Note that the versions are `work_version = "2.5.0"` and `workmanager_hilt_version = "1.0.0-beta01"` .

Then I went to my Worker class and typed `@HiltWorker` as described in the documentation BUT Android Studio could not find it:

```
@HiltWorker
class RefreshDataWorker @AssistedInject constructor(@Assisted appContext: Context, @Assisted params: WorkerParameters): CoroutineWorker(appContext, params) { ...// some doWork() stuff }
```

`@HiltWorker` is in red letters and Android Studios can not find it. Why ? Does sth. changed in Hilt ? Is there sth. missing in the documentation ?

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 3):

There are two choices:

1- Change "workmanager_hilt_version" from "1.0.0" to "1.0.0-alpha03". "@HiltWorker" is not available on "1.0.0"

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/hilt

2- Add the "hilt-work" dependency:

implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

Please change your workmanager hilt version from
workmanager_hilt_version = "1.0.0-beta01"
into
workmanager_hilt_version = "1.0.0"